# titlesec is not properly working with KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I am new to latex and I am using `titlesec` for formatting the chapter headings with `titlesec`.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge}
{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

but
I am not getting my chapter heading properly. I just get plain text.

I am also getting this warning. 
[image]
Is this a reason for it?

I have a created small MME

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have following result without package **titlesec**. [image]

Comment: You shouldn't use titlesec with koma classes. They are quite incompatible with each other and this is noted in the koma manual. Koma classes have functionalities to format title embedded.

Comment: Welcome! As  @ArTourter suggests, this combination is not recommended. You don't even need to read the documentation. The warning says exactly the same. But whether or not you follow the class's recommendation, we would need more information - in the form of a Minimum Working Example (MWE) - to help effectively. This should be code for the smallest document you can create which illustrates the problem. I.e. `\documentclass... \end{document}` such that, when we copy-paste-compile, we can reproduce the problem you want help with.

Comment: i have created small MME

Comment: Please make sure your code compiles before uploading it!

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class.

With KOMA-Version 3.19 or newer it is possible to insert title rules by redefining `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`:

```
\newcommand\titlerule[1][.4pt]{\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{#1}}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  {\raggedleft#2}\nobreak%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\kern-.5\baselineskip}{}%
  \titlerule\\*%
  \kern-.5ex%
  #3\par\nobreak%
  \kern1.75ex%
  \titlerule%
}
```

To change the skips before and after the chapter title and also between the chapterprefix and the title you can use `RedeclareSectionCommand`.

```
\documentclass[
  headings=chapterprefix
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  beforeskip=\dimexpr4.6\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1.5\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][.4pt]{\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{#1}}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  {\raggedleft#2}\nobreak%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\kern-.5\baselineskip}{}%
  \titlerule\\*%
  \kern-.5ex%
  #3\par\nobreak%
  \kern1.75ex%
  \titlerule%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\addchap{Test the second}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

If the lines should be also there without option `headings=chapterprefix` add a redefinition of `chapterlinesformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \titlerule\\*%
  \kern-.5ex%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}\par\nobreak%
  \kern1.75ex%
  \titlerule%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
 %headings=chapterprefix
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}

\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  beforeskip=\dimexpr4.6\baselineskip+\parskip\relax,
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=1.5\baselineskip plus .115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip
]{chapter}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][.4pt]{\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{#1}}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  {\raggedleft#2}\nobreak%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{\kern-.5\baselineskip}{}%
  \titlerule\\*%
  \kern-.5ex%
  #3\par\nobreak%
  \kern1.75ex%
  \titlerule%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \titlerule\\*%
  \kern-.5ex%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}\par\nobreak%
  \kern1.75ex%
  \titlerule%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\addchap{Test the second}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way to do it, but I hope somebody who knows the class will correct me.

Something like this?

[image: ruled chapter title]

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
% see manual esp. chapter 21
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{\@tempskipa}\hfill}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadmidvskip}{\vskip.5\@tempskipa\par\nobreak\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vskip.5\@tempskipa\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vskip.25\@tempskipa\par\nobreak\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\makeatother
\setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\huge}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\bfseries\Large}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \raggedchapter
  \@hangfrom{#2}#3%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \raggedleft
  #2%
  \raggedright
  #3%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:Introduction}
\end{document}
```